# How to display activity indicator in middle of the iphone screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

When we draw the image, we want to display the activity indicator.
Can anyone help us?

Comment: Try this link : http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/07/custom-activityindicator.html

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     
        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    activityView.center=self.view.center;
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

Comment: i would add also 


`activityView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;`


for proper landscape orientation look and rotation

Comment: @adsurbum Thank you! It was the key to make it centered on all size of iPhone screens from SE to 8 Plus! In Swift, it's:         
activityView.autoresizingMask = [
            .flexibleLeftMargin,
            .flexibleTopMargin,
            .flexibleRightMargin,
            .flexibleBottomMargin,
            .flexibleWidth,
            .flexibleHeight
        ]

Comment: +1 to adsurbum's comment. Setting the center stopped working in my app recently.  Setting the autoresizingMask fixed it. Before doing that it would just always appear in the upper left corner no matter what I set the .center to.

Answer (score 46):

If you are using Swift, this is how you do it

```
let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
activityView.center = self.view.center
activityView.startAnimating()

self.view.addSubview(activityView)
```

Answer (score 16):

*Code updated for Swift 3*

[image]

**Swift code**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)

    @IBOutlet weak var myBlueSubview: UIView!

    @IBAction func showButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    @IBAction func hideButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set up activity indicator
        activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: myBlueSubview.bounds.size.width/2, y: myBlueSubview.bounds.size.height/2)
        activityIndicator.color = UIColor.yellow
        myBlueSubview.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- You can center the activity indicator in middle of the screen by adding it as a subview to the root `view` rather than `myBlueSubview`.

  ```
  activityIndicator.center =  CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.size.height/2)
  self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
  ```
- You can also create the `UIActivityIndicatorView` in the Interface Builder. Just drag an **Activity Indicator View** onto the storyboard and set the properties. Be sure to check **Hides When Stopped**. Use an outlet to call `startAnimating()` and `stopAnimating()`. See [this tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/activity-indicator-tutorial-ios8-swift).

[image]

- Remember that the default color of the `LargeWhite` style is white. So if you have a white background you can't see it, just change the color to black or whatever other color you want.

  ```
  activityIndicator.color = UIColor.black
  ```
- A common use case would be while a background task runs. Here is an example:

  ```
  // start animating before the background task starts
  activityIndicator.startAnimating()

  // background task
  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

      doSomethingThatTakesALongTime()

      // return to the main thread
      DispatchQueue.main.async {

          // stop animating now that background task is finished
          self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 13):

This is the correct way:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
activityIndicator.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);
[self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

[activityIndicator release];
```

Setup your autoresizing mask if you support rotation. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4, Autolayout version**

```
func showActivityIndicator(on parentView: UIView) {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    parentView.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor),
        activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor),
    ])
}
```

Comment: Welcome to S/O, your answer should never be 100% code.. Always add some explanation.

Comment: Not sure if this is a black and white rule. If the scope of the question is simple enough and the code self-explanatory, I think it's totally fine to have an code-only answer. @Orkhan's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 4):

Try this way

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    activityIndicator.center = super_view.center;
    [super_view addSubview: activityIndicator];

[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add a text along with activity indicator please look at http://nullpointr.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/ios-dev-custom-activityindicatorview/

Comment: Your shared link is appreciated but you should make us understand the steps so that everyone gets the clean way to get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the position like this

```
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = 
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityView.frame = CGRectMake(120, 230, 50, 50);
[self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

Accordingly change the frame size.....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center the spinner using AutoLayout, do:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[activityView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:activityView];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:activityView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:activityView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0.0]];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3, xcode 8.1**

You can use small extension to place **UIActivityIndicatorView in the centre of UIView** and inherited UIView classes:

### Code

```
extension UIActivityIndicatorView {

    convenience init(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle, color: UIColor, placeInTheCenterOf parentView: UIView) {
        self.init(activityIndicatorStyle: activityIndicatorStyle)
        center = parentView.center
        self.color = color
        parentView.addSubview(self)
    }
}
```

### How to use

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge, color: .gray,  placeInTheCenterOf: view)
activityIndicator.startAnimating()
```

### Full Example

In this example UIActivityIndicatorView placed in the centre of the ViewControllers view:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge, color: .gray,  placeInTheCenterOf: view)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
}

extension UIActivityIndicatorView {

    convenience init(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle, color: UIColor, placeInTheCenterOf parentView: UIView) {
        self.init(activityIndicatorStyle: activityIndicatorStyle)
        center = parentView.center
        self.color = color
        parentView.addSubview(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 you can use the following:

```
 func setupSpinner(){
    spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height:40))
    spinner.color = UIColor(Colors.Accent)
    self.spinner.center = CGPoint(x:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2, y:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2)
    self.view.addSubview(spinner)
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work:

```
// create activity indicator 
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
[activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

...
 [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
// release it
[activityIndicator release];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try to do it by using interface, you can [view my video for this](http://youtu.be/Swskjb_9ELQ?t=10m10s).
This way, you no need to write any code to show Activity Indicator in the middle of the iPhone screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textLbl: UILabel!

    var containerView = UIView()
    var loadingView = UIView()
    var activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let _  = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: false) { (_) in
            self.textLbl.text = "Stop ActivitiIndicator"
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.containerView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func palyClicked(sender: AnyObject){

        containerView.frame = self.view.frame
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.3)
        self.view.addSubview(containerView)

        loadingView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 80)
        loadingView.center = self.view.center
        loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.5)
        loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
        loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        containerView.addSubview(loadingView)

        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
        activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x:loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, y:loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        loadingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thongchai! Can you add some additional text explaining your code?

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to display activity Indicator with minimum code:

first of all import your UI Kit

```
import UIKit;
```

Then you have to initiate activity indicator

```
let activityIndicator:UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView();
```

Then just copy paste this functions below which are self explainatory and call them whereever you need them:

```
func startLoading(){
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true;
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray;
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator);

    activityIndicator.startAnimating();
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents();

}

func stopLoading(){ 

    activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents();

}
```