# Loading gif in ScrollView

Tags: ios

I have an ActivityIndicator that appears while my Main View is being loaded. After clicking on one of the Cells within that view it takes me to a destinationViewController. In that controller I have a ScrollView that displays an image slideshow.

I want have the ActivityIndicator to appear while that slideshow loads. I also want it to be centered within the ScrollView (320 x 320).

Answer (score 1):

You should use activity indicator instead of your gif image.

See the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090579/how-to-display-activity-indicator-in-middle-of-the-iphone-screen) for using activity indicator and centering it.