# How to show activity indication on the centre of screen when tapping on OK button (using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer)?

Tags: ios, swift, api

How to show activity indication on the centre of screen when tapping on OK button ? I am using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer object and it show the Camera and when we scan the QR Code then alert box appears, after pressing OK button then it calls API and in this time, I want to appear the UIActivityIndicator.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class QRCodeScanner: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgClose: UIImageView!

    var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    var strQR = String()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Creating session
        let session = AVCaptureSession()

        //Capture device
        //var captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
            session.addInput(input)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error")
        }

        let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        session.addOutput(output)

        output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
        output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]

        video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        video.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(video)

        //Show Image in Camera Mode
        let myLayer = CALayer()
        let myImage = UIImage(named: "icn-close")?.cgImage
        myLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - CGFloat((myImage?.width)!) - 10, y: 16, width: 32, height: 35)
        myLayer.contents = myImage
        video.addSublayer(myLayer)


        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.view)

        session.startRunning()
    }


    @IBAction func btnClose(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }



    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
    {
        if metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            //qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            //messageLabel.text = "No QR code is detected"
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        let supportedCodeTypes = AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr

        if supportedCodeTypes == .qr {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata (or barcode) then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            //let barCodeObject = videoPwreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            //qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "QR Code", message: object?.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retake", style: .default, handler: nil))
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (nil) in

                self.strQR = (object?.stringValue)!
                //print("strQR")

                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                self.api(strURL: urlQRCode)
            }))

            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


            if object?.stringValue != nil {
                //launchApp(decodedURL: metadataObj.stringValue!)
                //messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
            }
        }

    }

    func api(strURL: String)
    {
        //URL
        let myURL = URL(string: strURL)

        //URL Request
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"


        //Passing the strOTP text in the dictionary variable
        let postString = ["qr_code": strQR]


        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let token = "Bearer " + strToken
        request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        do {
            // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
            request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options: .prettyPrinted)

            //print("Successfully passed data to server")
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        let postTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in

            //print(response!)

            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                //create json object from data
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                    print("POST Method :\(json)")

                    let dict = json as? [String: String]
                    let status = dict!["status"]
                    print("Status : \(String(describing: status))")

                    //Match the status code (received from response through the server
                    if dict!["status"] == "1"
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //Stop Activity Indicator
                            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                            print("The status received from server is 1. Entered Successfully to OTP Screen")
                            let thankVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThankYouVC") as! ThankYouVC
                            thankVC.strEmpName = dict!["whom_to_meet"]!
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(thankVC, animated: true)

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("The status received from server is 0.")

                        let whoopsPopupVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Popup_Whoops") as! Popup_Whoops
                        whoopsPopupVC.strDetail = "You are not a registered user."
                        self.navigationController?.present(whoopsPopupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                    // handle json...
                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        postTask.resume()
    }


}
```

Comment: This could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090579/how-to-display-activity-indicator-in-middle-of-the-iphone-screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display activity indicator in middle of the iphone screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090579/how-to-display-activity-indicator-in-middle-of-the-iphone-screen)

Comment: I am showing this activity indicator within the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer